# read the input name as a row in the database table

Tags: php, mysql, oop, web

when i try to add a new studio in my php application in this example i use newstudio as a name i get this error i think that it read the name i give as a row in the database table 
 Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Champ 'newstudio' inconnu dans field list'

```
private $conn;

public function __construct()
{
    $database = new Database();
    $db = $database->dbConnection();
    $this->conn = $db;
}
public function addStudio($sname,$sdes,$sidusr)
{
    $stmt = $this->conn->prepare("INSERT INTO studio (name,des,idusr) VALUES ($sname,$sdes, $sidusr)");
    $stmt->execute();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

if you have string value you should use single quote around these vars

```
public function addStudio($sname,$sdes,$sidusr)
{
    $stmt = $this->conn->prepare("INSERT INTO studio (name,des,idusr)
          VALUES ('$sname','$sdes', '$sidusr')");
$stmt->execute();
}
```

or you could use a parametrized  query

```
public function addStudio($sname,$sdes,$sidusr)
{
    $stmt = $this->conn->prepare("INSERT INTO studio (name,des,idusr)
          VALUES (:sname,:sdes, ':sidusr)");
    $stmt->bindParam(':sname', $sname);
    $stmt->bindParam(':sdes', $sdes);
    $stmt->bindParam(':sidusr', $sidusr);

    $stmt->execute();
}
```

Comment: Why not make use of `prepare()`, instead of adding quotes yourself?

Comment: The answer is strictly related  to the question ..  but your comment is lead a good suggestion   .. the OP could use a PDO parametrized  query  .. answer  updated

Answer (score 0):

Values require a `'` wrapped around it, but don't add it yourself.
You are already using `prepare()`, make use of it.

```
public function addStudio($sname,$sdes,$sidusr){
  $stmt = $this->conn->prepare("INSERT INTO studio (name,des,idusr) VALUES (?,?,?)");
  $stmt->execute([$sname, $sdes, $sidusr]);
}
```

Also, you should actually check the value of `$stmt` and verify if `execute()` did its job correctly.